# Database structure for categories, one main and then secondary ones (no sub-categories)

Tags: database, database-design, categories

I have to register a 5-digit number for a "Clients" table.
This number is actually the respective number for a category list from outside (not in my system). It's not needed to register more info (like category name) than the number, although it's a possible solution but it would require more work.
I will have one main category and then optional secondary categories (up to 2 or 3). These categories are all in the same level, one is not a category of another (no sub-categories).
What would be the best way to achieve this?

I thought of:
Option 1 - Have a column for the "main number" then another for "secondary-1 number", another for "secondary-2 number" and another for "secondary-3 number", with these "secondary numbers" columns being optional to fill.

Option 2 - Have a column for the "main number" and then another for the secondary numbers where an input could have more than one secondary number separated by a comma (example: "11111, 22222, 33333" ).

Option 3 - Have a table for these numbers like "Categories", then another table for the many-to-many relationship with the "Clients" table. Perhaps then having a column in the "Categories" table saying if it's "main category" or not.

Other options?

One of the goals would be to be able to list the Clients by Categories.

My low experience in database doesn't help me to see which option is the best one, or even correct one (as some options might not be recommended at all). So I was hoping someone with more experience could lead me.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Only "Option 3" is the correct design solution. As you wrote "*not needed to register more info*", the table `external_categories` is not required right now but can be added later.

```
clients                       client_ext_categories
-------                       --------  
id_client (PK)  --- 1:M ---<  id_client    (PK)
name                          category_num (PK) 
...
```